# Parse json with adding strings

Tags: python, bash

I have net.json config with tons of user commnets, parameters and flags. It looks like this:

```
/* First example */
{ "name" : "data_in", "port" : 10200, "fifo" : false },
```

And this:

```
/* Second example */
{ "name" : "some_test_in", "port" : 10205, "fifo" : false, "udp" : true },
```

I can't remove this comments. As you can see second example have this "udp":true flag. So, i need to create new net.json config that insert in every same looking as first example:

```
/* First example */
{ "name" : "data_in", "port" : 10200, "fifo" : false, "udp" : true },
```

But second example will be untouched:

```
/* Second example */
{ "name" : "some_test_in", "port" : 10205, "fifo" : false, "udp" : true },
```

I can't use any additional packets (like jq and etc). How to make script (python or bash) like this?

Comment: You want to remove comments? Use regex?

Comment: No, i need to add new udp flag in every string if it doesn't exist and skip if it exist

Comment: What's parsing this in the first place? JSON doesn't have comments.

Comment: In the first place parsing udp. I know that JSON doesn't have comments, but dumb people that created it like this won't change it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Are these comments listed as `dict` objects? If so:

```
for comment in comments:
    if "udp" not in comments:
        comment["udp"] = True
```

If they are stored as `str` use `json.loads` to convert them to `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop over your net.json config, you need to check if the object contains the attribute `"udp"` or not. One way would be to use `hasattr`

```
a =[{ "name" : "data_in", "port" : 10200, "fifo" : False, "udp" : True },
{ "name" : "data_in", "port" : 10200, "fifo" : False}
]
b = []
for i in a :
  if hasattr(i, "udp") :
    b.append(i)
  else :
    i["udp"] = False
    b.append(i)

print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

With using ** mapping:
sample data:

```
l = [
    { "name" : "data_in", "port" : 10200, "fifo" : False }, 
    { "name" : "some_test_in", "port" : 10205, "fifo" : False, "udp" : True },
    { "name" : "some_test_in", "port" : 10205, "fifo" : False, "udp" : False }]
```

udp value will be updated if exsist in d:

```
 [{'udp':True, **d} for d in l]
```

Results:

```
[{'fifo': False, 'name': 'data_in', 'port': 10200, 'udp': True},
 {'fifo': False, 'name': 'some_test_in', 'port': 10205, 'udp': True},
 {'fifo': False, 'name': 'some_test_in', 'port': 10205, 'udp': False}]
```